# PersistentVolumeMound Bound but with 0 capacity using Kubernetes on Google Compute Engine

Tags: kubernetes, google-kubernetes-engine

I'm experiencing a strange problem using k8s 1.3.2 on GCE. I have a 100GB disk set up, and a valid (and Bound) PersistentVolume. However, my PersistentVolumeClaim is showing up with a capacity of 0, even though its status is Bound, and the pod that is trying to use it is stuck in ContainerCreating.

Hopefully the outputs from kubectl below summarise the problem:

```
$ gcloud compute disks list
NAME                                 ZONE            SIZE_GB  TYPE         STATUS
disk100-001                          europe-west1-d  100      pd-standard  READY
gke-unrest-micro-pool-199acc6c-3p31  europe-west1-d  100      pd-standard  READY
gke-unrest-micro-pool-199acc6c-4q55  europe-west1-d  100      pd-standard  READY

$ kubectl get pv
NAME             CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   STATUS    CLAIM                           REASON    AGE
pv-disk100-001   100Gi      RWO           Bound     default/graphite-statsd-claim             2m

$ kubectl get pvc
NAME                    STATUS    VOLUME           CAPACITY   ACCESSMODES   AGE
graphite-statsd-claim   Bound     pv-disk100-001   0                        3m

$ kubectl describe pvc
Name:       graphite-statsd-claim
Namespace:  default
Status:     Bound
Volume:     pv-disk100-001
Labels:     <none>
Capacity:   0
Access Modes:

$ kubectl describe pv
Name:       pv-disk100-001
Labels:     <none>
Status:     Bound
Claim:      default/graphite-statsd-claim
Reclaim Policy: Recycle
Access Modes:   RWO
Capacity:   100Gi
Message:
Source:
    Type:   GCEPersistentDisk (a Persistent Disk resource in Google Compute Engine)
    PDName: disk100-001
    FSType: ext4
    Partition:  0
    ReadOnly:   false

# Events for pod that is supposed to mount this volume:
Events:
  FirstSeen LastSeen    Count   From                        SubobjectPath   Type        Reason      Message
  --------- --------    -----   ----                        -------------   --------    ------      -------
  6h        1m      183 {kubelet gke-unrest-micro-pool-199acc6c-4q55}           Warning     FailedMount Unable to mount volumes for pod "graphite-statsd-1873928417-i05ef_default(bf9fa0e5-4d8e-11e6-881c-42010af001fe)": timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "graphite-statsd-1873928417-i05ef"/"default". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[graphite-data]
  6h        1m      183 {kubelet gke-unrest-micro-pool-199acc6c-4q55}           Warning     FailedSync  Error syncing pod, skipping: timeout expired waiting for volumes to attach/mount for pod "graphite-statsd-1873928417-i05ef"/"default". list of unattached/unmounted volumes=[graphite-data]

# Extract from deploy yaml file:
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: pv-disk100-001
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 100Gi
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Recycle
  gcePersistentDisk:
    pdName: disk100-001
    fsType: ext4
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: graphite-statsd-claim
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteOnce
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 100Gi
---
```

Any help gratefully received!

Answer (score 1):

Dan, the first issue "PVC capacity 0" looks like a bug. I opened https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/29425 you can track it there.

The second issue sounds like https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/29166 which is currently under investigation. Feel free to add your repro information on there with your logs, and I'll take a look.